# Replace value text in Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink, treeview

Is there way to replace the value that is displayed (in this case a very long hyperlink) in a Tkinter treeview column with something shorter (but it still open the hyperlink)? The example I have is similar to the screenshot below, except the Google link is actually a very long OneNote link. I would like to be able to replace the text that is displayed with a "Click Here". So for this example, "Click Here" would take the user to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

[image]

The code I'm using to add the hyperlink is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser as wb

root=Tk()
root.title('Decision Tree')
root.geometry("600x600")

my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

#Define the columns
my_tree['columns'] = ("Decision", "Hyperlinks", "ID")


#format the columns
my_tree.column("#0", width=250, minwidth=100)
my_tree.column("#1", width=0, stretch="No")
my_tree.column("Hyperlinks", anchor=W, width=200)
my_tree.column("ID", anchor=CENTER, width=80)


#Create Headings
my_tree.heading("#0", text="Decision", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("#1", text="", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("Hyperlinks", text="Hyperlinks", anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("ID", text="ID", anchor=CENTER)

#Add Data (Top Level)
my_tree.insert(parent='', index='1', iid=0, text="Problem 1", values=("", "", "1"))
my_tree.insert(parent='', index='1', iid=2, text="Problem 2", values=("", "", "3"))
my_tree.insert(parent='', index='1', iid=1, text="Problem 3", values=("", "", "2"))

my_tree.tag_configure('tag1', foreground='Blue', font=('Helvetica' ,8, 'bold', 'italic'))

#Add child level 1
my_tree.insert(parent='0', index='end', iid=6, text="Prob 1 level 2", values=("", "www.google.com", "1.1"), tags='tag1',)
my_tree.insert(parent='1', index='end', iid=7, text="Prob 3 level 2", values=("", "www.google.com", "3.1"), tags='tag1',)
my_tree.insert(parent='2', index='end', iid=8, text="Prob 2 level 2", values=("", "www.google.com", "2.1"), tags='tag1',)

#Add child level 2
my_tree.insert(parent='6', index='end', iid=9, text="Prob 1 level 3", values=("", "", "1.11"))
my_tree.insert(parent='7', index='end', iid=10, text="Prob 2 level 3", values=("", "", "2.21"))

def open_link(event):
    tree = event.widget  # get the treeview widget
    region = tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y)
    col = tree.identify_column(event.x)
    iid = tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
    if region == 'cell' and col == '#2':
        link = tree.item(iid)['values'][1]  # get the link from the selected row
        wb.open_new_tab(link)  # open the link in a browser tab

# bind left-click to 'open_link'
my_tree.bind('<Button-1>', open_link)

#pack to the screen
my_tree.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `pyshorteners` module to change the long url to a shorter url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the links in a dictionary, with the key being whatever you want to display to the user. Then it’s just a matter of looking up the link when the user clicks.

Another alternative is to put the actual link in a hidden column.

Comment: I actually went for the dictionary method that you suggested and that seemed to work well.